# Model isn't validating

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, model

So, when putting in text for my model it is always valid, even though I explicitly asked for it to have a minLength despite it being empty or being less than the minLength.

Models:

```
public class CommentaarCreate_VM
{
    public Stad Stad { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Commentaar Commentaar { get; set; }
}
public class Commentaar
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentaarId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; } 
    [Required]
    public int StadId { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false, ErrorMessage="You need to enter a comment of valid length")]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage ="You need to enter a comment of valid length")]
    public string CommentaarText { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime Tijdstip { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model DataGent.Web.ViewModels.CommentaarCreate_VM

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Create new comment";
}
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Stad.Id" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Stad.Naam" />
        <input type="hidden" value="@Html.AntiForgeryToken()" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Commentaar" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Commentaar" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Commentaar.CommentaarText" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        CommentaarCreate_VM vm = new CommentaarCreate_VM()
        {
            Stad = _dataGentService.GetStadFromId(id),
            Commentaar = null
        };

        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind("CommentaarText, Tijdstip")] int id, IFormCollection collection) //Bind = protect from overposting
    {
        try
        {
            // Creating  object to POST
            Commentaar commentaar = new Commentaar
            {
                UserId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User),
                StadId = id,
                CommentaarText = collection["Commentaar"],
                Tijdstip = DateTime.Now
            };

            var result = _dataGentService.PostCommentaar(commentaar);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing? I thought all the work, except for the dataannotations, was done by MVC?

Comment: Check whether _ClientValidationEnabled_ and _UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled_ are set to _true_ in web.config under appsetting.

Comment: are you talking client side validation or server side?  On the server side you are never checking ModelState.IsValid. how would you know if your model state is valid or not?

Comment: @Fran Clientside validation.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal web.config apparently doesn't exist anymore in this version of ASP, I did try to manually enable it via the startup.cs services, but that changed nothing so I'm guessing it's on by default.

Answer (score 3):

Your input is:

```
<input asp-for="Commentaar" class="form-control" />
```

You have to change asp-for from Commentaar to Commentaar.CommentaarText so that it is validated:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Commentaar.CommentaarText" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Commentaar.CommentaarText" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Commentaar.CommentaarText" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Update:

Initialize Commentaar object in your viewmodel before you pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    CommentaarCreate_VM vm = new CommentaarCreate_VM()
    {
        Stad = _dataGentService.GetStadFromId(id),
        Commentaar = new Commentaar()
    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't work. I've made a new testing Create View that did all this by default for all the properties, but even though all of them have [required] as dataAnnotation it still never gives an error.

Comment: @Sven0567 can you get the input values from the client in your post action?

Comment: @Sven0567 may i ask why you use bind, instead of just returning CommentaarCreate_VM object?

Comment: Yes, I can get the input values from the post action, I could do this all manually but I'm just baffled why it doesn't do this automatically if it should be.  Also, I use bind to say that only those 2 props should be changed to prevent Overposting.

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is to use `ModelState.IsValid` on your post methods, in order to check properties of the model that is being sent. Said that, ModelState.IsValid checks for Data Annotations written by you on your Model.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind("CommentaarText, Tijdstip")] int id, IFormCollection collection) //Bind = protect from overposting
    {
         if(ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             //If it is valid, do all your business logic, like creating a new entry.
         }
         else
         {
             //Handle it
             return View();
         }
    }
```

Another thing is that I see that you use `ViewModels` which is good. So you could just send your viewmodel as a parameter for your action. You could do that as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CommentaarCreate_VM viewmodel)
    {
          if(ModelState.IsValid)
          {
               //It is valid
               //All your logic
          }
          else
          {
               //Not valid
               return View(Viewmodel model)
          }         
    }
```

By doing this, you have to add data annotations to `CommentaarCreate_VM`

```
  public class CommentaarCreate_VM
    {
        public Stad Stad { get; set; }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false, ErrorMessage="You need to enter a comment of valid length")]
        [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage ="You need to enter a comment of valid length")]
        public Commentaar Commentaar { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I tried adding the Annotations to the viewmodel, but that also didn't work, the ModelState.IsValid always returns true, even if the value is empty in the Input in the View and the property has a [Required] tag.

Comment: Maybe this will sound tricky but, have you tried Cleaning your solution and Building it again? Actually It happened me a lot of times, that changes on my models, like new data annotations to their properties, were not taken in count until I cleaned the entire solution and rebuilt it again.

Comment: Cleaned and rebuilt, forgot to do it before but it still didn't change anything sadly.

Answer (score 0):

So I've found atleast somewhat of a solution, but the underlying problem still stands. 
The problem is that in the controller the Modelstate.IsValid is always true, even if some of the models should not be valid so it just does what I want it to before redirecting to another page.
Solution is that I can get the error messages working if in the controller I check if the string is null or empty, and if so just Return(viewmodel), and that gets the error messages working.
Obviously, the Modelstate.IsValid SHOULDNT be returning true, and I still don't know why it does.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind("CommentaarText, Tijdstip")] int id, CommentaarCreate_VM viewModel, IFormCollection collection) //Bind = protect from overposting
    {
        try
        {
          //If incoming string is null or empty
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["Commentaar"]))
            {
                return View(viewModel);
            }
//This always returns true. It really shouldn't, because otherwise I wouldn't need that earlier check. 
//If the model isn't valid in the View, this one should be false, right?
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Creating  object to POST
                //.....

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```